How to test if spy init block calls a method using Mockk
Libraries
    testImplementation("io.mockk:mockk:1.13.12")

    val junitVintageVersion = "5.10.3"
    testImplementation("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:$junitVintageVersion")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$junitVintageVersion")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:$junitVintageVersion")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$junitVintageVersion")

I have a class, of which I want to create a Spy to verify that certain methods are being called. This specific class has an init block, which is supposed to handle some logic (simplified for this question, the actual use case involves flows etc.)
When I create a Spy of my class, however, it does not let me verify that one of my methods has been called, even though I know it has been.
Simplified example:
class Example {
    init {
        test()
    }

    fun testWrapper() = test()

    fun test() = println("test was called!")
}

class ExampleTest {
    @Test
    fun `testWrapper should call test`() {
        // ----- Arrange -----
        val instance = spyk<Example>()

        // ----- Act -----
        instance.testWrapper()

        // ----- Assert -----
        verify(exactly = 1) { instance.test() }
    }

    @Test
    fun `init should call test`() {
        // ----- Act -----
        val instance = spyk<Example>()

        // ----- Assert -----
        verify(exactly = 1) { instance.test() }
    }
}

In the example given below, the first test passed, but the second one fails...
When looking at the second test, I get the following output:
test was called!

Verification failed: call 1 of 1: Example(#231).test()) was not called
java.lang.AssertionError: Verification failed: call 1 of 1: Example(#231).test()) was not called
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.VerifyingState.failIfNotPassed(VerifyingState.kt:63)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.VerifyingState.recordingDone(VerifyingState.kt:42)
...

As a side note, the first test has the following output:
test was called!
test was called!

Which means that technically, it should never have passed in the first place, as the method itself has clearly been executed twice, not once.
For some reason, the method which is being called within the init block does not seem to be included within the created spyk object?
Is there any way to verify whether specific methods within the init block have been executed?
I am very new to testing, so it might be something simple I overlooked...
